# How can I set a breakpoint for a button click?

Tags: windows, ollydbg

I am trying to find what a button does, so I want to set a breakpoint to catch button click event. Is that possible?

Any tools or tricks to assist in this?

Comment: As Peter mentioned it depends on many things, what I usually do in Olly is pausing the program, and clicking on "Stop at user input" (or something similar to that), which will break when you press the button.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It very much depends on what framework they use in order to do their windowing. It could be [MFC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Foundation_Class_Library), [WPF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Presentation_Foundation), [WinForms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WinForms), [WTL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WTL), [QT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qt_%28software%29), [wxWidgets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wxwidget), pure [Windows API](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_API). There's a lot of frameworks and they all handle the final routing of messages differently.

I'll answer the question for the cases that are either directly built on top of Windows API or where they're using the Windows API directly. WPF does not use the Windows API windowing system other than for the outermost windows.

Initially the program registers a function that handles messages intended for a particular window. This can be done using the [RegisterClass](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633586(v=vs.85).aspx) or [RegisterClassEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633587(v=vs.85).aspx) functions. The function which will be responsible for handling the messages sent to the window is the lpfnWndProc member of the structures passed to these functions. This is called the window procedure.

What happens when a button is pressed is that a message, in this case [WM_COMMAND](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647591(v=vs.85).aspx), is pushed into the thread message queue by Windows. This message is then fetched using  [GetMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644936(v=vs.85).aspx) or [PeekMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644943(v=vs.85).aspx). Some messages use short cuts and can result in a call to the window procedure directly when you call GetMessage, some messages only result in a call to the window procedure when the application calls [DispatchMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644934(v=vs.85).aspx). If you're dealing with a dialog, the message will be handled by a call to [IsDialogMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645498(v=vs.85).aspx).

Now that we have some background on how this works behind the scenes, OllyDbg actually has a helper for dealing with this sort of thing. You can simply open the View->Windows dialog item. Right click the window you want to catch button presses in, select message breakpoint on classproc, select command and notifications from the message dropdown or select the WM_COMMAND message. Now whenever you click the button you will break in the window procedure the application registered for that window. You still need to trace the code so that you can find the code that examines the message type and then handles the message. From now on it will be different depending on what type of framework is being used.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comment , I tried what you said before and for some reason i never manage to find the application's function so i thought I'm doing it wrong .. I guess i need to try harder! Thanks!

Comment: A tip I can give you that I've used to get familiar with the windowing systems (although admittedly not all of them) is to code something up that uses the framework and have the call back be your own inline assembly (something obvious like 20 nops/int3s/etc) then find the function in your debugger/disassembler. You can trace it back from there to see what you could look for in a real sample. Depends on how you learn but it might help.

Comment: I've used this learning technique to learn most of reverse engineering tricks i know , didn't come to my mind this time though..Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

open calc.exe in ollydbg `c:\ollydbg.exe calc.exe`
press `Ctrl + G and type GetMessageW`
press `F2` to set a breakpoint and press `F9` until it breaks
when it is broken press `ctrl+f9` to run until return
press `shift+f4` to set a conditional log breakpoint
in the expression edit box type `[esp+4]`
in the decode value of expression `select pointer to MSG structure (UNICODE)`
set radio button pause to `never`
set radio button log expression to `Always`
hit `ok`
now look at log window for all the messages that are handled
refine your conditional breakpoint to handle only the cases you want to examine 
for example this condition will log only mouseup and wm_char messages

```
Breakpoints, item 1
 Address=7E41920E
 Module=USER32
 Active=Log when [[esp+4]+4] == WM_KEYDOWN || [[esp+4]+4] == WM_LBUTTONUP
 Disassembly=RETN    10
```

like results posted below notice the hwnd for each button you can refine to a multiple condition with a specifc Window Handle hWnd 2e048a etc

```
\Log data
Message
COND: 0007FEE8 WM_LBUTTONUP hw = 2E048A ("C") Keys = 0 X = 57. Y = 14.
COND: 0007FEE8 WM_LBUTTONUP hw = 10053E ("And") Keys = 0 X = 22. Y = 10.
COND: 0007FEE8 WM_LBUTTONUP hw = 200404 ("Xor") Keys = 0 X = 22. Y = 18.
COND: 0007FEE8 WM_LBUTTONUP hw = 270402 ("M+") Keys = 0 X = 22. Y = 11.
COND: 0007FEE8 WM_LBUTTONUP hw = D036A ("Sta") Keys = 0 X = 27. Y = 15.
COND: 0007FEE8 WM_LBUTTONUP hw = 1B04F0 ("x^2") Keys = 0 X = 18. Y = 17.
COND: 0007FEE8 WM_KEYDOWN hw = 1B04F0 ("x^2") Key = 35  ('5') KeyData = 60001
COND: 0007FEE8 WM_KEYDOWN hw = 4303EC (class="Edit") Key = 42  ('B') KeyData = 300001
COND: 0007FEE8 WM_KEYDOWN hw = 4303EC (class="Edit") Key = 41  ('A') KeyData = 1E0001
```

to simulate same in windbg put this commands in a txt file and run windbg  (you should have skywings sdbgext extension loaded for verbose display )

```
bp user32!GetMessageW "pt;gc"
g
bc *
.load sdbgext
bp @eip ".if (poi(poi(esp+4)+4) == 0x202) {!hwnd poi(poi(esp+4));gc } .else {gc}"
g

windbg  -c "$$>a< ......\wtf.txt" calc

Window    00600438
Name      And
Class     Button
WndProc   00000000
Style     WS_OVERLAPPED 
ExStyle   WS_EX_NOPARENTNOTIFY WS_EX_LEFT WS_EX_LTRREADING WS_EX_RIGHTSCROLLBAR 
HInstance 01000000
ParentWnd 00490534
Id        00000056
UserData  00000000
Unicode   TRUE
ThreadId  00000df0
ProcessId 00000f68
Window    00150436
Name      Xor
Class     Button
WndProc   00000000
Style     WS_OVERLAPPED
```

Comment: I wonder if x64dbg (open source, and still developed) can do same things.

Comment: Great post with detailed example. Very helpful.

Comment: @Ciantic it can https://x64dbg.com/blog/2017/07/07/messages-breakpoints-in-x64dbg.html