# How to set a Mouse Click BreakPoint in OllyDbg?

Tags: ollydbg, breakpoint

In the debugger program OllyDbg, How do I set a breakpoint when the left mouse button is pressed? It doesn't matter what it clicks on, so upon mouse click, the breakpoint stops the debugger.

Comment: See also [How can I set a breakpoint for a button click?](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/3288/how-can-i-set-a-breakpoint-for-a-button-click)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All messages in a gui application passes through the Application Defined Callback WinProc whose prototype is

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(
  _In_ HWND   hwnd,
  _In_ UINT   uMsg,
  _In_ WPARAM wParam,
  _In_ LPARAM lParam
);
```

so when you have breakpointed on a wndproc

```
esp    -> return Address
esp+4  -> hwnd 
esp+8  -> uMsg  
.....
```

[** MSDN Doc For List of messages**](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winmsg/about-messages-and-message-queues#system_defined)

to know a windoproc or class proc 
use alt+w  shortcut in ollydbg (opens a list of windows )
right click to open the context menu and follow Either Wndproc or ClassProc
for the appropriate window of choice

hit shift+f4 and set a log breakpoint that never pauses  and 
set the function type to be WndProc (Assume Function Of Type DropDown)

see screen shot below
[image]

and run the app

go to log window and observe you will see a lot of logs like this

```
00551EDE  Call to CALC.WndProc from USER32.77B4C4E4
            00010236  hWnd = 00010236, class = CalcFrame, text = Calculator
            00000210  Msg = WM_PARENTNOTIFY
            00000204  Event = WM_RBUTTONDOWN, ID = 0
            00230006  Data = 230006
00551EDE  Call to CALC.WndProc from USER32.77B4C4E4
            00030248  hWnd = 00030248, class = CalcFrame
            00000021  Msg = WM_MOUSEACTIVATE
            00010236  hParent = 00010236, class = CalcFrame, text = Calculator
            02040001  Hittest = HTCLIENT, MouseMsg = WM_RBUTTONDOWN
00551EDE  Call to CALC.WndProc from USER32.77B4C4E4
            00010236  hWnd = 00010236, class = CalcFrame, text = Calculator
            00000021  Msg = WM_MOUSEACTIVATE
            00010236  hParent = 00010236, class = CalcFrame, text = Calculator
            02040001  Hittest = HTCLIENT, MouseMsg = WM_RBUTTONDOWN
00551EDE  Call to CALC.WndProc from USER32.77B4C4E4
            00030248  hWnd = 00030248, class = CalcFrame
            00000020  Msg = WM_SETCURSOR
            00030248  hWnd = 00030248, class = CalcFrame
            02040001  Hittest = HTCLIENT, MouseMsg = WM_RBUTTONDOWN
00551EDE  Call to CALC.WndProc from USER32.77B4C4E4
            00010236  hWnd = 00010236, class = CalcFrame, text = Calculator
            00000020  Msg = WM_SETCURSOR
            00030248  hWnd = 00030248, class = CalcFrame
            02040001  Hittest = HTCLIENT, MouseMsg = WM_RBUTTONDOWN
00551EDE  Call to CALC.WndProc from USER32.77B4C4E4
            00030248  hWnd = 00030248, class = CalcFrame
            00000204  Msg = WM_RBUTTONDOWN
            00000002  Keys = MK_RBUTTON
            00230006  X = 6, Y = 35.
00551EDE  Call to CALC.WndProc from USER32.77B4C4E4
            00030248  hWnd = 00030248, class = CalcFrame
            00000084  Msg = WM_NCHITTEST
            00000000  wParam = 0
            01790207  X = 519., Y = 377.
00551EDE  Call to CALC.WndProc from USER32.77B4C4E4
            00030248  hWnd = 00030248, class = CalcFrame
            00000020  Msg = WM_SETCURSOR
            00030248  hWnd = 00030248, class = CalcFrame
            02050001  Hittest = HTCLIENT, MouseMsg = WM_RBUTTONUP
00551EDE  Call to CALC.WndProc from USER32.77B4C4E4
            00010236  hWnd = 00010236, class = CalcFrame, text = Calculator
            00000020  Msg = WM_SETCURSOR
            00030248  hWnd = 00030248, class = CalcFrame
            02050001  Hittest = HTCLIENT, MouseMsg = WM_RBUTTONUP
00551EDE  Call to CALC.WndProc from USER32.77B4C4E4
            00030248  hWnd = 00030248, class = CalcFrame
            00000205  Msg = WM_RBUTTONUP
```

now refine the breakpoint to suit your condition
(change from never to on condition
add condition  like when uMsg == WM_LBUTTONDOWN  ie
[esp+8] == 0x20x..20y (see the stack layout mention earlier
0x200 t0 0x220 are WM_MOUSE EVENT MESSAGES

here is screenshot that shows a possible configuration and result below screen shot
[image]

```
00551EDE  INT3: [esp+8] = WM_MOUSEMOVE
00551EDE  INT3: [esp+8] = WM_NCHITTEST
00551EDE  INT3: [esp+8] = WM_PARENTNOTIFY
00551EDE  INT3: [esp+8] = WM_MOUSEACTIVATE
00551EDE  INT3: [esp+8] = WM_MOUSEACTIVATE
00551EDE  INT3: [esp+8] = WM_SETCURSOR
00551EDE  INT3: [esp+8] = WM_SETCURSOR
00551EDE  INT3: [esp+8] = WM_LBUTTONDOWN
00551EDE  Call to CALC.WndProc from USER32.77B4C4E4
            00030248  hWnd = 00030248, class = CalcFrame
            00000201  Msg = WM_LBUTTONDOWN
            00000001  Keys = MK_LBUTTON
            00350004  X = 4, Y = 53.
00551EDE  INT3: [esp+8] = WM_NCHITTEST
00551EDE  INT3: [esp+8] = WM_SETCURSOR
00551EDE  INT3: [esp+8] = WM_SETCURSOR
00551EDE  INT3: [esp+8] = WM_LBUTTONUP
00551EDE  INT3: [esp+8] = WM_NCHITTEST
00551EDE  INT3: [esp+8] = WM_PARENTNOTIFY
00551EDE  INT3: [esp+8] = WM_MOUSEACTIVATE
00551EDE  INT3: [esp+8] = WM_MOUSEACTIVATE
00551EDE  INT3: [esp+8] = WM_SETCURSOR
00551EDE  INT3: [esp+8] = WM_SETCURSOR
00551EDE  INT3: [esp+8] = WM_RBUTTONDOWN
00551EDE  Call to CALC.WndProc from USER32.77B4C4E4
            00030248  hWnd = 00030248, class = CalcFrame
            00000204  Msg = WM_RBUTTONDOWN
            00000002  Keys = MK_RBUTTON
            00350004  X = 4, Y = 53.
00551EDE  INT3: [esp+8] = WM_NCHITTEST
00551EDE  INT3: [esp+8] = WM_SETCURSOR
00551EDE  INT3: [esp+8] = WM_SETCURSOR
00551EDE  INT3: [esp+8] = WM_RBUTTONUP
```

Answer (score 1):

Regardless of operating system, a mouse click represents an event and there is a bunch of event handling plumbing that makes this happen. Some of this can hinge upon certain design choices like how processes are separated in the GUI.

A common pattern is to register a context relative to which events can be processed through an implemented handler. Traditionally under Windows, this is a "Window Class" and practically everything is a window. The definition of that window class includes a function/method that handles the events/messages sent to the target window. To target a specific window with a debugger, you would want to break on a condition where the message/event handling function is called with the event you want (like [`WM_LBUTTONDOWN`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/inputdev/wm-lbuttondown) on Windows). There are cases where default handling of events can occur as well, a la [`DefWindowProc()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-defwindowproca).

Doing this in a broader context would require hooking that is facilitated by the operating system, perhaps at the kernel level. There may be other options for you available through [Hooks](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winmsg/about-hooks).