# Mouse click breakpoint

Tags: ollydbg, breakpoint

Im just start to learn and stuck with problem: trying to set breakpoint on mouse click, but ollydbg log shows me only new thread created or terminated.
I did as it is written in these threads:
[Thread 1](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/3288/how-can-i-set-a-breakpoint-for-a-button-click)
[Thread 2](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/19212/how-to-set-a-mouse-click-breakpoint-in-ollydbg)

There is my steps:
Press `ctrl+G` -> search for `USER32.GetMessageW` -> press `shift+F4` and set decode expressions as `message code (WM_xxx)`, assume func as `winprocw`, pause program - never, log value of expressions - always, log func args - always -> OK and going to log window.
Maybe i did something wrong?