# Windows GUI app without GetMessage imported?

Tags: windows, unpacking

I am currently trying to reverse an app and I have one very stupid question I cannot figure out by myself.

The app was packed using FSG 2.0 and I successfully manually unpacked it and rebuilt the IAT (at least I believe I did).
The app is a Windows 32 bits PE and it has a small GUI (it's a crackme that has one simple input and once you click ok, it just replies goodboy or badboy).

From what I can see, it imports the SendMessage function and actually uses it but I can't find any GetMessage (nor PeekMessage) function imported.
Considering it is a GUI, is that even possible ?

Any hints appreciated !

Comment: If the binary resolves those functions dynamically at run-time using `GetProcAddress` (or other methods) you won't have a corresponding entry in the IAT.

Comment: Thank you Sir for your answer. :) I didn't think about that. In that specific case, the binary doesn't even call GetProcAddress. However, for what it's worth, there is also a really good answer (the ticked one) that is related to my question here : https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/3288/how-can-i-set-a-breakpoint-for-a-button-click.

Comment: Much of the functionality for GDI32 and User32 has some implementation in the NT Native API. So there's a chance some function from there gets called and does the equivalent of GetMessage. Also, no need to call `GetProcAddress()` ... either use the NT Native API as well or better yet, walk the export table and find your desired function by hash. [The technique](http://www.hick.org/code/skape/papers/win32-shellcode.pdf) is **ancient** in terms of "internet time".

Comment: Thanks for all your insight, much appreciated !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case of it could be useful to someone else, I finally managed to understand how the Windows messages are handled in the program I'm trying to reverse (rather simple in fact). It's calling DialogBoxParamA (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-dialogboxparama) : the before last parameter is a pointer to the procedure in charge of handling the messages.